# News of potential interest to the MO community

Tags: discussion

Occasionally, there has been a suggestion to start a meta question to collect information that might be of interest to the MO community.  This is an attempt to start such a thread.

Is there any news that you think would be of wide interest to the MO community?  Please exercise your discretion in any answers, and your judgement on the appropriateness or significance of any event.

Comment: nice idea but SE meta is not really a good format for this. suggest starting a (community) blog somewhere or twitter acct etc. also try [chat]

Comment: As of now, four of five answers report someone's death -- is this almost the only type of "News of potential interest to the MO community"? I do not doubt that these reports are of interest, in particular the one of today -- but would it perhaps make sense to adjust the question accordingly, as for several months hardly any other news turned up here?

Comment: @StefanKohl:  By all means add news that is more positive, if appropriate.  I left the question deliberately open ended.

Comment: One can add, eg, the Fields medal winners (+Nevanlinna etc) next year when they are announced.

Comment: I think reporting any important enough result or new development in mathematics would be fine as well, and at least equally interesting as news about who has died or who has got this-or-that award.

Comment: It seems that this is mainly an "Obituaries column", rather than general news. I sure hope there will be some good news posted here sometime soon...

Comment: @Asaf some good news, at last! Also, JDH will be somewhat closer geographically for you, FWIW

Comment: @David: Having known about this for a few months now, this is not a surprise for me. I also complained that this is not exactly "MO News". I didn't see anyone congratulate me for winning the Newton International Fellowship (nor I expected that to happen, nor I wish it to have happened). I didn't see anyone congratulate any other user on their fancy grants or new positions. Yes, this is a happy news, as opposed to the whole dead people thing. But it's not something that I find as relevant news to the site. As much as I am happy that Joel will be closer now, which I am, let me assure you that.

Comment: @Asaf of course you would know :-) but it makes a change from "so-and-so died :-(..."

Comment: @Emilio: Yes,  I agree that there is a troubling feeling over the most of this page.

Comment: @AsafKaragila:  When I posted this question, I also flagged it myself so that the moderators can assess its suitability and asked them to delete it if they thought fit.  By and large, this question and the answers have been uncontroversial -- the answers have been appropriate and respectful, and I see very few downvotes.   I'm sure you or others may find something troubling about this -- I don't see it myself.  In any case, surely there is room for differing viewpoints on this.

Comment: @Asaf Ah. I had deleted my comment after seeing the comments to the first answer. But on second thought I do stand by it: there is something about having voting arrows next to a series of obituaries that makes me deeply uncomfortable. Votes on a single answer are OK, but when there's several and the default sorting is by votes, it's much more complicated. I see the value in a noticeboard with those announcements, but this format has some awful features.

Comment: @Lucia: I don't think it should be closed or deleted or anything. And I agree that it has some relevance here. Nevertheless, it still feels a bit odd, in part for the reasons that Emilio mentions.

Comment: @Lucia (and is there a way to ping the mods?) is there a way to set the default answer sorting for this thread to newest first?

Comment: Should this thread be CW perhaps?

Comment: @AsafKaragila what does CW mean on meta?

Comment: @FrançoisG.Dorais: More users can edit answers with relevant information.

Comment: @StefanKohl:  I removed your edit, since I don't see its relevance to the question.  I get the sense that you don't like the question or the answers, and that is certainly your prerogative.  But it doesn't seem correct to me that the question should be edited with a comment aimed at discouraging answers.

Comment: @Lucia: I didn't mean to discourage answers in any way -- just the contrary. Actually I find the question as such good (I upvoted it already a long time ago). My edit was merely to give a quick overview of what answers are currently there, and to encourage more non-obituary answers. If the edit read like I wanted to discourage answers, then I am sorry, and in this case it was indeed good to revert it.

Comment: @StefanKohl:  Thanks for your response!  I'd prefer the question as it is.  Of course as it is CommunityWiki, everyone has an equal right to edit it, and I  don't insist upon my view.

Comment: Robin Chapman https://mathoverflow.net/users/4213/robin-chapman was a valued contributor to MathOverflow in its early years. He passed away, unexpectedly, on 18 October 2020. An obituary can be found at the website of the Math Department at the University of Exeter. http://emps.exeter.ac.uk/mathematics/news-events/news/articles/robinchapmanobituary.html

Comment: @gerrymyerson:  Thank you for sharing this.

Comment: @Steven if you are so inclined, you could post this item as an answer here. I can only post comments on meta, not answers.

Comment: @GerryMyerson:  Done, though this leaves me intensely curious about why you can't post answers on meta.

Comment: Unfortunately, Professor Peter Antonelli passed away in 2020.

Comment: Maybe there should be a separate thread for people dying. Or, at this point, one for people not dying.

Comment: There seems to be a serial downvoter of obituary answers. It sounds puerile.

Answer (score 49):

[Igor Shafarevich died on February 19, 2017 in Moscow at the age of 93.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Igor_Shafarevich)

Comment: Can one upvote news like this -- or is there a risk that the meaning of an upvote here is misunderstood?

Comment: I think one should understand upvotes to news of this type simply as a mark of respect.  At least that's how I would take it.

Comment: Perhaps if meta had a link called "thanks" instead of just "upvote" Stefan's question wouldn't arise. Though like Lucia, my upvote here is simply also as a mark of respect; additionally, I also view my upvote here as a note of thanks to Lucia for bringing this news to the attention of the MO community.

Comment: My upvote here is a show of respect to IG.

Answer (score 49):

The American Mathematical Society (https://www.ams.org/news?news_id=6987), the London Mathematical Society (https://www.lms.ac.uk/node/1848), and the Société mathématique de France (https://smf.emath.fr/actualites-smf/23-02-22-icm-en-russie), and possibly other math societies around the world, have called for the 2022 ICM to not be held in St. Petersburg, in response to Russian aggression against Ukraine.

EDIT: And now the IMU has made a statement: https://www.mathunion.org/fileadmin/IMU/Publications/CircularLetters/2022/IMU%20AO%20CL%204_2022.pdf

EDIT 2: Probably everyone has already seen this on the MO frontpage, but it is now official, the 2022 ICM will take place entirely online, at the same time as originally scheduled: https://www.mathunion.org/fileadmin/IMU/ICM2022/ICM_2022_statement.pdf

Comment: Canadian Mathematical Society: https://cms.math.ca/news-item/official-statement-regarding-the-russian-invasion-of-ukraine-and-participation-in-the-2022-icm-and/

Comment: The Australian Mathematical Society: https://austms.org.au/statement-on-icm-2022/

Answer (score 48):

[Maryam Mirzakhani has died of breast cancer.](http://www.bbc.com/news/science-environment-40617094) A professor at Stanford University, she was the first female (and first Iranian) recipient of the Fields Medal. She was only 40 years old.

Answer (score 45):

As nobody mentioned this here so far -- since last month (January 2021), [zbMATH](https://zbmath.org/) is completely open access.

Comment: That is fantastic news! Perhaps this will increase pressure for [Mathscinet to follow suit](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/13619/is-a-free-alternative-to-mathscinet-possible).

Answer (score 41):

[Spectacular Olympic victory](https://www.bbc.co.uk/sport/olympics/57960575) in cycling by EPFL postdoc [Anna Kiesenhofer](https://arxiv.org/search/math?searchtype=author&query=Kiesenhofer%2C%20A)

Comment: I have also mentioned this at the "non-math achievements by mathematicians" thread.

Comment: deeply impressive; here is a (translated) commentary by our [national news paper:](https://www.nrc.nl/nieuws/2021/07/25/een-kapitale-vergissing-verbreekt-de-olympische-wielerdroom-a4052284)  _The Dutch women grossly underestimated Anna Kiesenhofer from the hamlet of Kreusztetten. She should never have been given eleven minutes in the game of her life. Asked for tips for young riders, the brand new champion inadvertently sent a message to the Dutch team: "Don't trust anyone blindly." That's how she had come here._

Comment: Wow!! Thanks for that answer!

Answer (score 38):

John Conway passed away on April 11, 2020, at age 82: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/John_Horton_Conway

Comment: Yes, I just heard the sad news too.  Thanks for adding this.

Comment: Not disputing this account, but it is worth noting that someone has edited the wikipedia page to remove the death notice (presumably pending verification)

Comment: @YemonChoi:  I heard this before seeing it on wikipedia, from a very reliable source.

Comment: @Lucia Sure, I just meant that Sam's link should be replaced/updated for now, otherwise people will click on it and potentially be confused

Comment: There is a short note on the [talk page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Talk:John_Horton_Conway#Death) of that Wikipedia article.

Comment: More detailed confirmation: https://twitter.com/CardColm/status/1249088354857226242 

Comment: "From 5 of his close associates" https://twitter.com/CardColm/status/1249082119567138819?s=20,

Comment: Article in Mercer Daily Voice, a New Jersey newspaper: https://dailyvoice.com/new-jersey/mercer/obituaries/covid-19-kills-renowned-princeton-mathematician-game-of-life-inventor-john-conway-in-3-days/786461/ If you speak Dutch, there's https://www.nrc.nl/nieuws/2020/04/12/wiskundige-conway-was-een-speels-genie-en-kenner-van-symmetrie-a3996590 In German, https://www.golem.de/news/covid-19-mathematiker-john-conway-ist-gestorben-2004-147842.html

Comment: In Spanish, https://www.unocero.com/ciencia/muere-matematico-john-conway-covid-19/  And in Turkish, https://halktv.com.tr/bilim-ve-teknoloji/matematikci-john-conway-coronavirus-nedeniyle-yasamini-yitirdi-423009h

Comment: From Princeton University's news site: https://www.princeton.edu/news/2020/04/14/mathematician-john-horton-conway-magical-genius-known-inventing-game-life-dies-age and from the New York Times (paywall), https://www.nytimes.com/2020/04/15/technology/john-horton-conway-dead-coronavirus.html

Comment: At that August 2022 the journal Notices of the American Mathematics Society Vol. 69, No.  7 published the articles *Conway’s Mathematics After Conway* (pages 1145-1155) and *John Horton Conway (1937–2020)* (MEMORIAL TRIBUTE, pages 1171-1187). I add the articles if some user wants to know these articles.

Answer (score 33):

Sadly we just lost another Fields medallist, [Vladimir Voevodsky died suddenly](https://www.ias.edu/news/2017/vladimir-voevodsky).

Answer (score 31):

Alan Turing will appear on the [Bank of England](https://twitter.com/bankofengland/status/1375002034060070912/photo/1)'s new ${\large\unicode{xA3}} 50$ note -- with a photo, a quote, and some lines from his 1936 [paper](https://londmathsoc.onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/abs/10.1112/plms/s2-42.1.230) in the *Proceedings of the London Mathematical Society*: "On Computable Numbers, with an Application to the *Entscheidungsproblem*."
[image]

Answer (score 27):

Not an obituary, but not good news either.

There seem to be an effort to eliminate pure mathematics from the University of Leicester. Anyone who is interested in signing a petition to try and raise awareness of how severe of a mistake this may be can do so here:

https://www.ipetitions.com/petition/mathematics-is-not-redundant

The ironic part is that the proposed change is under a restructuring effort named "Shaping for Excellence". Please help to spread the word.

Comment: I'm not sure why the downvote. This isn't the first time these sort of petitions are posted on MO. I just didn't feel that it merits a separate thread.

Comment: Seems a good point to raise here.  Thanks for adding this.

Comment: This is doubly dispiriting/appalling given that the university had tried something similar back in 2016...

Comment: @Yemon: That is terrible.

Answer (score 27):

[Mark Sapir](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mark_Sapir) died on October 8, 2022. He was a long-term MO contributor.

[Obituary notice at Vanderbilt's site](https://news.vanderbilt.edu/2022/10/26/mark-sapir-vanderbilt-mathematician-and-esteemed-scholar-has-died/)

Comment: Long-term user whose contributions remain after he left, now attributed to 'user6976'.

Comment: It seems that Professor Sapir also posted under [markvs](https://stackexchange.com/users/2944634/markvs).

Comment: correct me if I'm wrong, but the switch to "user6976" happened because the account was deleted by the user, not because the user passed away.

Answer (score 26):

Atiyah passed away on Friday (11th Jan), confirmed by [Oxford Maths dept](https://web.archive.org/web/20190111193302/https://www.maths.ox.ac.uk/node/31190), [the Royal Society](https://web.archive.org/web/20190111173233/https://royalsociety.org/news/2019/01/tribute-to-former-president-of-the-royal-society-sir-michael-atiyah/) and an [obit in the NYT](https://www.nytimes.com/2019/01/11/obituaries/michael-atiyah-dead.html).

Comment: Thanks for posting.  That's sad to hear.

Answer (score 23):

The 2018 Fields medal winners are Caucher Birkar, Alessio Figalli, Peter Scholze, and Akshay Venkatesh. Brief citations and longer descriptions of their work are available on [the IMU website](https://www.mathunion.org/imu-awards/fields-medal/fields-medals-2018).

Peter Scholze has explained some of the key ideas in his research on MO, most notably in [this introductory post](https://mathoverflow.net/a/66563/18060tqs).

Comment: Constantinas Daskalakis (sp?) Is the Nevanlinna prize winner, and David Donoho for Gauss prize. When I get to see the names for Leelavati and Chern winners, I will post them.  Gerhard "Sincere Congratulations To Them All" Paseman, 2018.08.01.

Comment: Masaki Kashiwara for Chern prize.  Gerhard "Finally Seeing The Laudatio Lectures" Paseman, 2018.08.01.

Comment: Ali Nesin for Leelavati. Gerhard "That's The List For Today" Paseman, 2018.08.01.

Answer (score 23):

The recipients of the [2022 Fields medals](https://www.mathunion.org/imu-awards/fields-medal/fields-medals-2022) were announced (in this order) at ICM 2022:

- Hugo Duminil-Copin
- June Huh
- James Maynard
- Maryna Viazovska

The Ladyzhenskaya medal was awarded to Svetlana Jitomirskaya, the Abacus medal was awarded to Mark Braverman, the Gauss prize to Elliott H. Lieb, the Chern medal to Barry Mazur, and the Leelavati prize to Nikolai Andreev.

Answer (score 21):

**Congratulations to J.D. Hamkins**

Please join us in wishing [J.D. Hamkins the best of luck](http://jdh.hamkins.org/oxford-university-professor-of-logic/) as Professor of Logic in the Faculty of Philosophy at Oxford University, and
Sir Peter Strawson Fellow in Philosophy, University College, Oxford. Hopefully he'll continue his contributions to this site.

Comment: Thank you very much; you are so kind to take notice. Yes, indeed, I expect I shall be carrying on as usual with MathOverflow while in Oxford. Or perhaps I should say, "whilst"?

Answer (score 20):

Jim Humphreys has passed away. This  was confirmed by Paul Gunnells [https://people.math.umass.edu/~gunnells/](https://people.math.umass.edu/%7Egunnells/)
and is implied by https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/James_E._Humphreys

Comment: I'm sorry to hear that; thanks for letting us know.

Comment: https://mathoverflow.net/users/4231/jim-humphreys

Answer (score 20):

The American Mathematical Society now has a streamlined process for mathematicians who have changed their names and who wish to update their papers published under the old name to be listed under the new one.

https://www.ams.org/publications/journals/policies/authornamechanges

Answer (score 20):

Yuri Manin passed away on January 7, 2023.

Comment: [Obituary](https://www.linkedin.com/posts/hausdorff-center_max-planck-institute-for-mathematics-in-bonn-activity-7017826108146335744-mw9a) by the Hausdorff Center for Mathematics.

Answer (score 19):

[Marina Ratner, Professor at Berkeley, died on July 7, 2017.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marina_Ratner)

Answer (score 19):

[Alan Baker (1939-2018) died on 4 February 2018](https://www.trin.cam.ac.uk/news/tributes-paid-to-professor-alan-baker/). Baker received the Fields medal in 1970 for his work in transcendental number theory.

Comment: A great pity :'(

Answer (score 18):

[Vaughan Jones](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vaughan_Jones) has passed away at the age of 67. I think others on MO may be better placed than me [YC] to comment on the depth and impact of his work on subfactors and his introduction of what became known as the Jones polynomial in knot theory.

[Link to article in New Zealand Herald](https://www.nzherald.co.nz/nz/news/article.cfm?c_id=1&objectid=12363385#:%7E:text=New%20Zealand%27s%20most%20celebrated%20mathematician,a%20recent%20severe%20ear%20infection)

Comment: I was sorry to hear that.   The Wikipedia page does mention this, but the exact date seems unclear as you say.

Answer (score 18):

There is now a plaque in Paris (between the Luxembourg Gardens and the Pantheon) to commemorate the first meeting of Bourbaki (10 December 1934) at their local Burger King!

[image]

Comment: Just to be clear, I don't think Bourbaki met at a Burger King, I think a Burger King was opened, many years later, next to the site of the Bourbaki meeting.

Comment: @GerryMyerson:  I wondered if anyone would really think that, but I'm surprised that you should raise it! I think the Burger King occupies abstractly the same space that  Bourbaki concretized. (See the plaque; and Bourbaki concretizing something is a nice joke in itself.)

Comment: I never shrink from stating the obvious, Lucia.

Comment: Fun false fact: the name *Bourbaki* comes from a mispronunciation of *Burger King*, the place where they first met in 1934.

Comment: @FedericoPoloni:  I was sent this with a fantastic caption to the photo:  BourbaKing!

Comment: A Starbucks would have been a happier compromise between mathematics and American fast food.

Answer (score 17):

Maria Yakerson has asked me to post the following announcement, since it could be interesting for the MO community

> Dear all,
>
> I would like to announce the YouTube channel "Math-life balance", where I am posting my online-interviews with mathematicians:
>
> https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCYRR0SgbYH59htIHkwTbqMw
>
> In these non-professional interviews I ask our colleagues about their personal experience in math, about different aspects of mathematician's job, about their struggles and lifehacks. I imagine, it could be useful for our community, especially for young mathematicians. While we discuss serious matters, there's a lot of laughter and storytelling involved, so I hope that would be a new source of joy during lockdown time!
>
> I plan to post videos on Fridays at 6 pm CET. The first interview, with Inna Zakharevich (Cornell University), is already available today. The second interview, with Hélène Esnault (Freie Universität Berlin), will be available next Friday. The updates to the schedule of interviews will appear here:
>
> https://www.muramatik.com/math-life-balance/
>
> A side-note: I've turned off comments on the channel in order to avoid inappropriate comments from spammers, often appearing on Youtube (and I can't moderate a discussion elsewhere myself, sorry!). In case you have comments, critics or encouragement for me, feel free to send me an email!
>
> Please spread the word! I would especially appreciate if you share the link with your students.
>
> All the best,
> Mura Yakerson

Comment: Some good news for once! Thanks for putting this here.

Comment: Just came to this thread to post this.  I've really enjoyed these interviews and learned a lot.

Answer (score 17):

I am very sad to report that [Joël](https://mathoverflow.net/users/9317/jo%c3%abl) Bellaïche, a long-term contributor to MO, passed away on Monday, 30 May 2022.

Comment: That's very sad news.

Answer (score 14):

[Jacques Tits](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacques_Tits) died on December 5, 2021, aged 91.

He won the [Abel prize](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abel_Prize) in 2008 "For his profound achievements in algebra and in particular for shaping modern group theory."

Answer (score 13):

[Robin Chapman](http://mathoverflow.net/users/4213/robin-chapman)  was a valued contributor to MathOverflow in its early years. He passed away, unexpectedly, on 18 October 2020. An [obituary](http://emps.exeter.ac.uk/mathematics/news-events/news/articles/robinchapmanobituary.html) can be found at the website of the Math Department at the University of Exeter.

Thanks to [Gerry Myerson](https://mathoverflow.net/users/3684/gerry-myerson) for letting us know.

Comment: He solved an amazing number of the problems posed in the *American Mathematical Monthly*---quite a talent.

Answer (score 13):

I might be behind the times here, but there is a [Quanta article](https://www.quantamagazine.org/new-math-book-rescues-landmark-topology-proof-20210909/) giving some history behind Freedman's classification of topological 4-manifolds and reporting on the new book [*The Disc Embedding Theorem*](https://global.oup.com/academic/product/the-disc-embedding-theorem-9780198841319) by Behrens–Kalmar–Kim–Teichner–Ray which sets out a complete proof. It makes interesting reading for those of us who are concerned about the evanescent nature of mathematical knowledge if left unattended.

Passing reference is made to the 2012 MO post [Independent evidence for the classification of topological 4-manifolds?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/87674/independent-evidence-for-the-classification-of-topological-4-manifolds)

(It is possible that this answer duplicates some other reference to the 5-person book, in which case I am happy for this to be deleted and merged into that other answer.)

Comment: Such a well-written article on a difficult-to-explain topic!

Answer (score 12):

There is an "[Open Letter](https://sites.google.com/view/k12mathmatters/home) on K-12 Mathematics" signed by some 750 people in the past two days, including various MathOverflow users (and two users with top-ten reputations). The letter focuses on math in public schools, especially in California, and the issues include:

- Should schools teach algebra before high school?
- Should schools emphasize or offer rigorous calculus vs less rigorous data science classes in high school?
- In what grade should students be split into different math classes,
  vs one class for the whole grade?
- How can the curriculum help students from diverse backgrounds acquire useful mathematical skills?

For background on the California Mathematics Framework at issue, I found some stories in [EdSource](https://edsource.org/2021/california-math-guidance-sparks-new-curriculum-controversy-among-parents/655272) and [CalMatters](https://calmatters.org/education/k-12-education/2021/11/california-math/) helpful. Meanwhile two of the letter-organizers argue their case in a recent guest [post](https://scottaaronson.blog/?p=6146) on Scott Aaronson's blog.

Comment: This seems to me to be of interest limited to one given country.

Comment: I don't know, it might be of international interest, if only addressed to an international audience, which I believe is currently not (neither the post, nor the linked page).

Comment: As with everything else on MO, one need not expect that any question or answer would be of interest to everyone.

Comment: @YCor, I edited in hopes of interesting more people.

Comment: @MattF. thanks, I appreciate it.

Comment: California gave us right turn on red light.

Comment: @GerryMyerson: surely not in Australia?

Comment: @Lucia, correct, we don't even have left turn on red yet.

Comment: @Gerry: I didn't know that Australia had cars. I thought everything is done via Cessna or helicopters.

Comment: @Asaf, I usually just hop on a kangaroo to get around, but we still have to obey the road rules.

Answer (score 12):

Abel Prize for 2024 [awarded to Michel Talagrand](https://abelprize.no/article/2024/michel-talagrand-awarded-2024-abel-prize) Félicitations!

Comment: [Here's a link to an interview](https://michel.talagrand.net/Talagrand.pdf) of Talagrand in 2019 in Gazette de la SMF (in French). Here's also [Talagrand's web page](https://michel.talagrand.net/), including some open problems.

Comment: Even if Michel adds his Abel Prize money to what he offers for solutions his problems, the amount will pale in comparison to the difficulty of his problems.

Answer (score 11):

The following was posted to the Algebraic Topology mailing list by Eric Friedlander:

> Andrei Suslin passed away today, July 10 2018 at the age of 67. 
>   Andrei has  been one of the leading algebraists of the past 50 years,
>   establishing many of the basic theorems in algebraic K-theory,
>   instrumental in the development of motivic theories in algebraic
>   geometry, and a powerful influence in the study of the cohomology of
>   finite group schemes.  His mathematics has always been elegant; his
>   attitude has always been one of generosity.

Answer (score 11):

[Ron Graham](https://mathshistory.st-andrews.ac.uk/Biographies/Graham/) passed away.

Comment: A lovely video on Ron's life and work: https://vimeo.com/136044050 .

Answer (score 11):

[Kenneth Kunen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kenneth_Kunen) passed away yesterday, August 14.

Kunen is best known for his work in set theory and set-theoretic topology.

https://www.math.wisc.edu/node/829

Comment: Oh no! How did that happen?

Comment: Do you have any sources that Wikipedia could cite? I started a discussion on the talk page

Comment: Hi @Asaf. I don't have any details. I learned of it through one of his former students. Apparently he had heart problems.

Comment: @David Hi David, I added a link.

Comment: @Andrés thanks. I see there was some activity on WP back and forth, so it's good to be able to pin things down.

Answer (score 11):

Jamie Haddock (Harvey Mudd), David Jekel (UCSD) and Christelle Vincent (U Vermont) are organizing an effort to reimburse early career mathematicians who lost funds to non-reimbursable travel expenses due to the cancellation of the JMM. Fill out [this poll](https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSeAGWyS7wIuIL2hkXw_BMw_aul22v0PCROu5mXLYwrBLYfw0w/viewform) to be considered for support; contact davidjekel@gmail.com to contribute time or money.

I am not involved in organizing this effort, but am simply spreading the word. [Relevant Twitter thread](https://twitter.com/doctor_jekel/status/1478840522248957952).

Comment: JMM is the  2022 Joint Mathematics Meetings (JMM) originally scheduled to be held in Seattle, January 5-8. https://www.jointmathematicsmeetings.org//jmm

Answer (score 10):

[Èrnest Borisovich Vinberg](//translate.google.com/translate?sl=ru&tl=en&u=https%3A%2F%2Fru.wikipedia.org%2Fwiki%2F%D0%92%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B1%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B3%2C_%D0%AD%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82_%D0%91%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%87) passed away (“from coronavirus pneumonia”) on May 12, 2020.

Answer (score 10):

Logician [Martin Davis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Martin_Davis_(mathematician)), best known for his contribution to the solution of Hilbert’s 10th problem, and development of the DPLL satisfiability algorithm, died on 1 January, 2023 in Berkeley at the age of 94, followed shortly by his wife Virginia.

Comment: I always appreciated his moderation of the Foundations of Mathematics e-mail list. My favorite memory of him is from Nov 7, 2000, a nighttime email exchange about some question of mine as a FOM participant, while both of us stayed up for more election results. RIP.

Answer (score 9):

Jacques Neveu died on May 15, 2016 at the age of 83. 
A day in homage to the famous french probabilist will be held on may 23, 2017 at IHP. Registration is free yet mandatory.

https://journee-neveu.sciencesconf.org/

[image: journee Jacques Neveu]

Answer (score 9):

[Raymond Hoobler](https://mathoverflow.net/users/20674/ray-hoobler) died on April 29 (of covid-19). See the [obituary](https://twitter.com/GC_CUNY/status/1258853759729438721).

Answer (score 9):

On November 10, 2020, we lost [Harold Mortimer Edwards](https://math.nyu.edu/faculty/edwardsd/), one of the few modern mathematicians to understand pre-modern (Galois, Kronecker, Dedekind) algebra and to attempt the demanding task of exposing it for modern readers. [Obituary](https://www.news-gazette.com/obituaries/harold-edwards/article_124f11b0-27a0-11eb-ab12-5cb9017bdfdf.html).

Comment: Thanks for letting us know.   I really liked his books on the zeta function, and on Fermat (pre-Wiles).

Answer (score 9):

Sadly, we lost [Jean-Pierre Demailly](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jean-Pierre_Demailly), who passed away yesterday (March 17, 2022) in Grenoble. [SMF notice (in French)](https://smf.emath.fr/actualites-smf/deces-de-jean-pierre-demailly)

Comment: Thanks for letting us know.

Answer (score 8):

I am reliably informed that [C.S. Seshadri](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C._S._Seshadri) has passed away in Chennai (July 17, 2020).

Answer (score 8):

[Sergey Natanzon](https://www.hse.ru/en/org/persons/14026884)
(Сергей Миронович Натанзон), 1948-2020, passed away on December 7, 2020, in Moscow, from covid-19 complications. His main research was in Fuchsian groups and Riemann surfaces. More on his work is [here](http://www.mathjournals.org/mmj/vol8-4-2008/natanzon-birthday.html).

Answer (score 8):

André Haefliger, retired professor in Geneva, passed away on March 7, 2023, aged 93.

https://www.ihes.fr/en/tribute-to-andre-haefliger/

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Andr%C3%A9_Haefliger

He had [many PhD students](https://www.mathgenealogy.org/id.php?id=28275), among which Vaughan Jones (1952-2020, Fields medal 1990).

Answer (score 8):

Here's a piece of good news for once: [Claire Voisin has won the 2024 Crafoord Prize for Mathematics!](https://www.kva.se/en/news/this-years-crafoord-laureates-can-see-inside-stars-and-describe-geometric-shapes/)

Here's a video on it: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aE5-WGyS6h8

(Nota Bene: Prof Voisin is the first woman mathematician to win this prize)

Answer (score 7):

> "Statement on scientific publications by three national Academies
>   (*Academie des sciences, Leopoldina*, and *Royal Society*)"

https://www.leopoldina.org/uploads/tx_leopublication/2016_Joint_Statement_on_scientific_publications.pdf

Comment: This is interesting, but at least for math journals the recommendations seem mostly superfluous.  I would guess that most good journals follow similar practices, and the predatory ones are hardly likely to care.

Comment: @Lucia I'm not saying that the statement is ideal or even that I agree with everything written there (though it is a step in the right direction, IMHO). I'm just saying that it is something I'd like to attract people's attention to.

Comment: No complaints from me!

Comment: @Lucia: Why do you think that the recommendations seem superfluous for math journals? -- I don't think they are -- also in mathematics there appear to be more and more journals where the peer-review doesn't work as it should ([arbitrary-chosen example](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1362.32018)), and also in mathematics it happens at times that referee's reports lack professionality (personal attacks on authors and the like). -- What I find objectionable in the statement is though the idea of per-article payments to 'fund' open-access -- it simply doesn't seem realistic to me to make (continued) --

Comment: (cont.): such payments independent from the decision to accept an article. Also, who would pay possible article processing charges for authors based in low-income countries, or for authors who are not affilitated with an institution? -- In my opinion, it would be best to make scientific publications exempt from copyright altogether (just as any type of documents where the copyright protection serves the only purpose to feed a publisher, and the benefit for the author is typically equal to zero).

Comment: @StefanKohl:  The example you linked seems to be from a nonsense journal.  As I mentioned in my remark, good journals already follow practices similar to the ones mentioned, and the corrupt (strictly for profit) ones are unlikely to change in any meaningful way.  APC's for open access is a complicated issue, but in the journals that I am aware of (or have been involved with), exceptions are always made to anyone who cannot afford them.   Also, some countries seem to have negotiated good deals with publishers regarding open access, which may be a different way forward.

Comment: @Stefan Kohl "Also, who would pay possible article processing charges for authors based in low-income countries, or for authors who are not affilitated with an institution?" My stance is much stronger: by sharing my knowledge by publishing I do a service to the community, so if somebody should be paid here at all, it is I. I can forfeit the reward, but that's where I draw the line. Arguments like the above sound to me like if the journal publishers asked that authors kiss their asses and the objection is that some people have back/knee problems, so it is hard for them to bend that low or kneel

Comment: Worth a plug: https://freejournals.org/ https://www.fairopenaccess.org/

Answer (score 6):

[Anatoly Vershik](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anatoly_Vershik) (12.28.1933-02.14.2024) passed away.

Answer (score 5):

If I am reading this chart from the AAAS correctly,
on "[Mathematical Sciences in the FY 2016 Budget](https://www.aaas.org/fy16budget/mathematical-sciences-fy-2016-budget),"
the funding for math in the U.S. went down by \$3 million dollars
(rounded, without adjusting for inflation) from 2015 to 2016.
I would be interested to learn the trend in other countries.

[image: Math Budget]

Comment: I don't see where you got that figure from, even given your image.

Comment: I think a more important question here is what the net value of the funding actually is -- i.e. after deducting reasonable wages for the time people spend on writing applications for these funds (both successful and unsuccessful ones) -- and how that changes over the years.

Comment: @DavidRoberts: $(235+122+97)-(232+129+96) = -3$. LIkely more accurate than using the rounded numbers in each small category.

Comment: @StefanKohl: I take your point, but the estimates you suggest using would be very difficult to calculate---time spent on writing; unsuccessful grants.

Comment: Is there any kind of new figures for more recent times? (I hesitate to say "this year")

Comment: It seems the situation is quite unclear. Here is one article addressing the US 2018 budget: [AMS link](https://blogs.ams.org/capitalcurrents/2018/03/23/we-probably-have-a-budget-for-2018-whats-in-it-for-the-mathematical-sciences/).

Answer (score 5):

[H. Garth Dales](https://www.lancaster.ac.uk/maths/people/garth-dales), formerly of Leeds University and Lancaster University, died on October 08, 2022 at the age of 78.

Comment: As one of Garth's colleagues, I have taken the liberty of correcting the details. I had not thought to post anything on MathOverflow since I did not know if this was "news of potential interest to the MO community".

Answer (score 5):

[Peter Aczel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peter_Aczel) passed away on August 1st, 2023.

Answer (score 5):

[Bernard Malgrange](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernard_Malgrange) (born in 1928, PhD L. Schwartz 1955), passed away on January 5, 2024, aged 95.

[SMF obituary](https://smf.emath.fr/actualites-smf/deces-de-bernard-malgrange) (in French)

Answer (score 5):

Nicolas Bergeron ([French Wikipedia](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nicolas_Bergeron_(math%C3%A9maticien)), [English Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nicolas_Bergeron)) sadly passed away on February 15, 2024, aged 48, after battling illness.

The [ENS-PSL obituary](https://www.ens.psl.eu/actualites/disparition-de-nicolas-bergeron) (in French).

Comment: The news about Bergeron came as a shock and it is always deeply saddening to hear of a young person's passing.

Answer (score 4):

Robert May, former UK chief scientist and chaos theory pioneer, dies aged 84. [Obituary](https://www.theguardian.com/science/2020/apr/29/robert-may-former-uk-chief-scientist-led-chaos-theory-lord-dies-aged-84) in The Guardian.

Answer (score 4):

Professor [Ivo Babuška](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ivo_Babu%C5%A1ka) passed away on 12 April 2023 at the age of 97. [Obituary](https://www.math.cas.cz/documents/parte_I_Babuska_EN.pdf)

Answer (score 4):

[Robert Zimmer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robert_Zimmer) passed away on May 23, 2023.

https://news.uchicago.edu/story/robert-j-zimmer-chancellor-emeritus-and-13th-president-university-chicago-1947-2023

Answer (score -4):

Yesterday I wondered (after I remember a course that I've seen where they refer a mathematician who was awared with the Crafoord Prize) if it could be suitable edit this post with the *List of mathematical awards* that provides the online encyclopedia Wikipedia [1].

As you see/know the list is very complete, and I think that this could be a good post to celebrate these awards. If this isn't the best post about this subject or my post isn't suitable in this post thread feel free to add a comment that I can to delete my post as soon as I can.

### References:

[1] https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_mathematics_awards

Comment: I emphasize my respect for this thread of posts. I add again that if some professor or moderator have a better idea to celebrate this list of mathematics awards I can to delete my post, many thanks.